# livereload reload my web page without changes files

Tags: html, angularjs, livereload

i don´t know why my web page reload when i add new register, the diference between next code is the form tag. Whith the first code the page is reloaded and the second code without form tag page isn´t reloaded, I can´t understand why. Could someone help me?

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="mybranchofficeCtrl">
 <h2>Mis Salas</h2>
 <!--newRoom input-->
 <form role="form">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="room.rooms.name" placeholder="Crea tu Sala">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="newRoom()" value="Añadir">
     </span>
   </div> 
  </div> 
 </form>
 <p></p>
 <p class="input-group" ng-repeat="room in rooms.data">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="room.name">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="disableRoom($index)" arial-label="delete">X</button>
  </span>
 </p>
</div>
```

but with this no, what is the diference?

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="mybranchofficeCtrl">
 <h2>Mis Salas</h2>
 <!--newRoom input-->
 <div class="row">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="room.rooms.name" placeholder="Crea tu Sala">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="newRoom()" value="Añadir">
    </span>
  </div> 
 </div> 
 <p></p>
 <p class="input-group" ng-repeat="room in rooms.data">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="room.name">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="disableRoom($index)" arial-label="delete">X</button>
  </span>
 </p>
</div>
```

these are controllers i´m using whith html code.

```
$scope.newRoom = function() {
        $scope.room.rooms.branchoffice_id = $scope.branchId;
        butlerService.createRoom($scope.room).then(function(newroom) {
            $scope.rooms.rooms.push(newroom);
        });
    }
$scope.disableRoom = function(index) {
        var delroom = {};
        delroom = {rooms:{id:$scope.rooms.data[index].id}}
        butlerService.deleteRoom(delroom).then(function() {
            $scope.rooms.data.splice(index,1);
        });

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: clear your cache! then hit f5

Comment: i can´t understand you, the problem is, when i add a newRoom the page auto reload when it should´t. Can you explain better please. Thanks.

Comment: i misunderstood the problem